# NLP Categorization Model

Tags: python, nlp, classification

I know in advance I'll get negative votes but I feel like this is the best place to get a good answer. I am planning to build a classification model using NLP which will basically assign a bucket(category) to a product based on it's description column. Which will be a long string with multiple words in it.

Is there a preferred type of model in this types of applications that would be recommended?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not really ? Try using word embedding into LSTM as a base model

Comment: It's general text classification. It's very standard and there are many algorithms. The first choice is whether to go with traditional methods (Naive Bayes, Decision Trees, SVM...) or with DL. Of course DL usually performs better but (1) requires more training data and (2) more computational resources for training.

Comment: @Erwan The amount of training data that I have in my hands I would presume that can be considered as plenty. However by more computational resources what do you mean?

Comment: It's best to start out with simpler, traditional approaches and establish a baseline. You can then try experimenting with different DL methods if you have the required resources (ideally accelerators for training/fine-tuning DL models)

Comment: @Alexchristof20 I mean that the training is longer (or requires a good GPU as opposed to regular CPU). I agree With A.T.B that it's always better to start with a simple version as baseline, and improve later,